# Popup more details on hovered without affecting surrounding components

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm trying to show more details and scale a component when hovered, but it displaces the surrounding components in doing so.

See screenshot:

[image]

Here's the sx I assigned to an MUI Box and Card.

```
const ctCardHoveredSx = {
  maxWidth: 300,
  '& .ct-card-toggle': {
    display: 'none'
  },
  '&:hover .ct-card-toggle': {
    display: 'flex'
  },
  '& .ct-card': {
    transition: 'transform 0.15s ease-in-out',
    boxShadow: 'none'
  },
  '&:hover .ct-card': {
    transform: 'scale3d(1.25, 1.25, 1)',
    boxShadow: '5',
    zIndex: 2
  }
};
```

Tech Stack:

- NextJS
- MUI
- React

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use overflow hidden in the parent div and it will not displace the thing and hover will just get scale inside the same div.

Please let me know if you find any issues.